# understanding proof urysohn's lemma

Tags: general-topology

On Folland's Real analysis the proof is given as follows.

> 4.15 Let $X$ be a normal space. If $A,B$ are disjoint closed subset of $X$, then there exists $f\in C(X,[0,1])$ such that $f|_A=0$ and $f|_B=1$.

> Proof:By lemma 4.14 there exists $r\in \Delta=\{k2^{-2}: n\geq 1 ,0<k<2^n\}$ such that $A\subset U_r \subset B^c$. Define $f(x)=\inf\{r\in \Delta: x\in U_r\}$, Since $0<r<1$ and $A \subset U_r$ we have $f(A)=0$ and there no $r$ such that $B\subset U_r$ hence $f(B)=1$. Now to show that $f$ is continuous, we look at $x\in f^{-1}(-\infty,y)$ then $f(x)< y$, hence there exists $r\in \Delta$ such that $x\in U_r$ and hence we have $f^{-1}(-\infty,y)=\cup_{r<y}U_r$. For $x\in f^{-1}(y,\infty)$ we have $f(x)>y$ which implies $x \not \in U_r$ for some $r\in \Delta$ iff $x\notin \overline{U}_s$ for some $s>y$. So we have $f^{-1}(y,\infty)=\cup_{s>y}(\overline{U}^c)$. Hence $f$ is continuous since every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is generated by $f^{-1}(y,\infty)$ and $f^{-1}(-\infty,y)$. For $y\in \mathbb{R}$.

What I dont understand for a while is how can we look at preimage of $f$, when $f(X)=[0,1]$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}$, how does $x\in f^{-1}(-\infty,y)\implies f(x)<y$, I mean what if $y <0$? then how can $f(x)\in [0,1] $ but $f(x)<y$.

Comment: If $f^{-1}(-\infty,y)=\varnothing,$ there is nothing to prove. That is why the author only considers the case $f^{-1}(-\infty,y)\ne\varnothing,$ i.e. the existence of some $x$ s.t. $f(x)<y$, which implies $y>0.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you! This bothered me for days!